# Using a Function Argument as a Dynamic Variable

Tags: swift, dynamic

Is there any way to make this work without resorting to calling the subscript directly?

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
final class Fuzzy {
    private var backing: [String: String] = [:]
    subscript(dynamicMember key: String) -> String? {
        get {
            return backing[key]
        }
        set {
            backing[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}

let fuzz = Fuzzy()

func worksFine() {
    fuzz.hello = "hi :)"
    print(fuzz.hello!)
}

// *** HERE WOULD LIKE TO PASS ARG DYNAMICALLY
func canThisWork(with arg: String) {
    print(fuzz\.arg)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without resorting to calling the subscript directly"? Do you mean, without doing this: `print(fuzz[dynamicMember: arg])`?

Comment: yea, but mostly just for practice, I see now I was misunderstanding a few bits of key paths :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use [KeyPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath) if you only want to access the value:

```
func canThisWork(with arg: KeyPath<Fuzzy, String?>) {
    print(fuzz[keyPath: arg]!)
}
```

Or [WritableKeyPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/writablekeypath) if you also want to mutate it:

```
var fuzz = Fuzzy()

func canThisWork(with arg: WritableKeyPath<Fuzzy, String?>) {
    fuzz[keyPath: arg] = "hi :)"
    print(fuzz[keyPath: arg]!)
}
```

In both cases you call your function like this:

```
canThisWork(with: \.hello)
```